# MS Access Hide Button on Startup

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to write code to only show a button during certain months of the year. I think I have the code down, but I don't know where to put it to make it work. When I put the code in "on paint", I get a 32521 error code: "You can't change the value of this property in the OnPaint event."

Here's the code:

```
Button.Visible = False

If ( (Month(Now) = 6) Or (Month(Now) = 7) Or (Month(Now) = 8) ) Then
Button.Visible = True
End If
```

Where should I put this code to make it run right when the home screen form is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Load Event

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Button.Visible = False

If ( (Month(Now) = 6) Or (Month(Now) = 7) Or (Month(Now) = 8) ) Then
    Button.Visible = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Or one-line: `Me.Button.Visible = Month(Now) = 6 Or Month(Now) = 7 Or Month(Now) = 8` and consider the OnCurrent event instead if form is bound and will navigate records.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!